# How to implement a multi role-Based User web application with Firebase vuex and Vue?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, firebase-authentication, vuex

I want to give My Firebase users 3 different roles(which can be expanded easily),reader author and admin

Admin :Can edit or delete any post(from a special admin interface)

Author:Can edit posts(a different interface from the admin)

Reader:Can only read data(same interface as the author but different roles)

I want this role based strategy because it is an excellent option for apps that have different user tiers and access levels

I can see a perfect implementation of this in angular but none in vue

Comment: This is probably too broad of a question to elicit concise answers.  There is a vue implementation of firebase which can be found here https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire  Also the vue documentation examples section might give an idea how to start https://vuejs.org/v2/examples/firebase.html.  A quick google search seemed to reveal a multitude of articles on implementing vue and firebase.   Once you get started if you run into specific programming questions, errors, etc. we will be here for you.

Comment: how much are you willing to pay us?